# VMware Workstation keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

When working in full screen mode, I'd like a way to quickly switch between host and VM using a toggle key. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: There is a default key of Right-Ctrl+Right-Alt to switch to the host. Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

From VMware's [Setting Configuration Options on the User's Computer](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_special_config.html) :

> **Hot Keys for Switching Directly to Virtual Machines and the Host Computer**
>
> You can specify a hot key or hot key
>   combination for switching directly to
>   any available virtual machine on a
>   host computer. Each time you press the
>   specified hot key, the screen display
>   switches to that of the specified
>   virtual machine. You may also specify
>   a hot key for switching directly to
>   the host operating system.
>
> If any particular virtual machine is
>   not running, pressing the hot key for
>   that virtual machine has no effect.
>
> You define the hot key used to switch
>   to a virtual machine by adding a line
>   to the target virtual machine's
>   configuration (.vmx) file. The value
>   of this option defines the hot key. It
>   is specified as *key,modifier*.
>   There is no default.
>
> For example, to use Ctrl-Shift-F1 to
>   switch to a particular virtual
>   machine, add the following line to
>   that virtual machine's .vmx file, or
>   modify its value if the option is
>   already listed.
>
> > FullScreenSwitch.directKey = "0x70,0x6"
>
> You define the hot key used to switch
>   to the host operating system by adding
>   a line to the global configuration
>   file (config.ini). The value of this
>   option defines the hot key. It is
>   specified as *key,modifier*. There
>   is no default.
>
> For example, to use Ctrl-Shift-F9 to
>   switch to the host operating system,
>   add the following line to the
>   config.ini file, or modify its value
>   if the option is already listed.
>
> > FullScreenSwitch.hostDirectKey = "0x78,0x6"

Comment: Note that those instructions were specific to the `vmware-fullscreen.exe`, which no longer exists.  It's since been replaced with `vmware-kvm.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know a single keystroke way, however if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to release the capture of the Mouse and keyboard, followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it should allow you to quickly switch to another window on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VMware KVM (which ships with VMware Workstation and VMware Player) to switch among virtual machines and the host using a configurable hotkey.  You can run `vmware-kvm.exe --preferences` to configure it and run virtual machines via `vmware-kvm.exe FILE.vmx`.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched that question myself and so far i have been able to come up with not so ideal solution, since it involves using a third part program.

What you can do is install a virtual desktop manager and have you VM running full-screen on the 2nd desktop. Then you can select a hotkey in a VD manager to switch between desktops.

Although this will still require 2 keystroke actions: one action to switch to the 2nd desktop and then another action (keystroke or mouse click) for the VM to grab input.

And of course, the same goes for the other way around, first you have to hit the hotkey to ungrab the input and then another hotkey to switch to your 1st desktop where you have your host system running.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can download VMWare tools which will enable you focus on the host and guest OS just by clicking. I.e. you are able to move out of the Guest screen to the Host and clicking anything in the Host screen will change the focus to Host OS.

Comment: Yes, you can but the question is about keyboard shortcuts so that you don't have to use your mouse at all.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Left & Ctrl-Alt-Right works for me